# Weird webpack bundle file being created after upgrading to SignalR v8.0

Tags: signalr

We upgraded to SignalR v8.0 and are using webpack to bundle our application script files. Webpack is now generating a weird bundle file named _ffca-_26cd-_6695-_e09b-_b4de-_fcc7.js with the following contents:

```
(self.webpackChunkverify=self.webpackChunkverify||[]).push([["_ffca-_26cd-_6695-_e09b-_b4de-_fcc7"],{"?ffca":
/*!**********************************!*\
  !*** abort-controller (ignored) ***!
  \**********************************/()=>{},"?26cd":
/*!*****************************!*\
  !*** eventsource (ignored) ***!
  \*****************************/()=>{},"?6695":
/*!******************************!*\
  !*** fetch-cookie (ignored) ***!
  \******************************/()=>{},"?e09b":
/*!****************************!*\
  !*** node-fetch (ignored) ***!
  \****************************/()=>{},"?b4de":
/*!******************************!*\
  !*** tough-cookie (ignored) ***!
  \******************************/()=>{},"?fcc7":
/*!********************!*\
  !*** ws (ignored) ***!
  \********************/()=>{}}]);
```

The files listed in this bundle are all the dependencies listed for the signalR package.

We now have to include this additional script file on our page to get our scripts to work. So, we have reverted to 7.0.14 for the time being until we can figure out what is going on here.